# Why isn't `regex!` a wrapper for `Regex::new` to offer the same regex matching speed?

Tags: rust, rust-compiler-plugin

The [Rust Regex crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) offers the `regex!` syntax extension which makes it possible to compile a regex during the standard compile time. This is good in two ways:

- we don't need to do that work during runtime (better program performance)
- if our regex is malformed, the compiler can tell us during compilation instead of triggering a runtime panic

Unfortunately, the docs say:

> **WARNING:** The `regex!` compiler plugin is orders of magnitude slower than the normal `Regex::new(...)` usage. You should not use the compiler plugin unless you have a very special reason for doing so.

This sounds like a completely different regex engine is used for `regex!` than for `Regex::new()`. Why isn't `regex!()` just a wrapper for `Regex::new()` to combine the advantages from both worlds? As I understand it, these syntax-extension compiler plugins can execute arbitrary code; why not `Regex::new()`?

Comment: Nice one, it's something that can indeed puzzle newcomers who didn't follow the development of the crate!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is very subtle: one feature of the macro is that **the result of `regex!` can be put into *static* data**, like so:

```
static r: Regex = regex!("t?rust");
```

The main problem is that `Regex::new()` uses heap allocations during the regex compilation. This is problematic and would require a rewrite of the `Regex::new()` engine to also allow for static storage. You can also read [burntsushi's comment about this issue on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3b2i0f/psa_regex_is_now_slower_than_regexnew/csi9n3c/).

---

There are some suggestions about how to improve `regex!`:

- Drop the `static` support and just *validate* the regex string at compile time while still *compiling* the regex at runtime
- Keep the `static` support by using a similar trick as `lazy_static!` does

As of the beginning of 2017, the developers are focused on stabilizing the standard API to release version 1.0. Since `regex!` requires a nightly compiler anyway, it has a low priority right now.

However, the compiler-plugin approach could offer even better performance than `Regex::new()`, which is already super fast: since the regex's DFA  [could be compiled into code instead of data](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/45yxcz/psa_regex_got_a_lazy_dfa_its_fast/d02648z/), it has the potential to run a bit faster and benefit from compiler optimizations. But more research has to be done in the future to know for sure.

Comment: What I personally would like to see is a `const fn` story sufficiently advanced to allow allocating memory, such that a Regex could be compiled at compile-time without any trick... may never see the light of day and would not help much for the Lazy DFA approach.

Comment: I think "potential to run a lot faster" is overstating things. Otherwise, good answer. :-)

Comment: @BurntSushi5 psssh, what do you even know about it anyway? (For others: BurntSushi5 is the primary author of the regex crate ^_^)

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I slightly edited the sentence ;-) I guess I just really like the idea that regexes could compile down to the exact code, I would have written by hand (or probably even better code!).